# Создать dictionary из stdin

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x

Приветствую!
Имеется некий текстовый файл со следующим содержимым (это только кусок, там много таких блоков)

```
Server 0x1ec28c0 (test1)
    Server:                              test1.ru
    Status:                              Slave, Running
    Protocol:                            MySQLBackend
    Port:                                3306
    Server Version:                      123-log
    Node Id:                             12
    Master Id:                           13
    Slave Ids:                           
    Repl Depth:                          1
    Slave delay:                         0
    Last Repl Heartbeat:                 Fri Aug 25 15:38:49 2017
    Number of connections:               23
    Current no. of conns:                1
    Current no. of operations:           0
Server 0x1ec1a50 (test2)
    Server:                              test2.gn
    Status:                              Master, Running
    Protocol:                            MySQLBackend
    Port:                                3306
    Server Version:                      023-log
    Node Id:                             13
    Master Id:                           -1
    Slave Ids:                           12, 19 
    Repl Depth:                          0
    Last Repl Heartbeat:                 Fri Aug 25 15:38:59 2017
    Number of connections:               456
    Current no. of conns:                7
    Current no. of operations:           0
```

Который через `cat filename.txt | my_script.py` подаётся в stdin python'а. Подскажите пожалуйста, как всё это распарсить в словарь, чтоб получилось примерно следующее:

```
{
"test1": {
    "Server": "test1.ru",
    "Status": "Slave, Running",
    "Protocol": "MySQLBackend",
    "Port": "3306",
    "Server Version": "123-log",
    "Node Id": "12",
    "Master Id": "13",
    "Slave Ids": "",                           
    "Repl Depth": "1",
    "Slave delay": "0",
    "Last Repl Heartbeat": "Fri Aug 25 15:38:49 2017",
    "Number of connections": "23",
    "Current no. of conns": "1",
    "Current no. of operations": "0"
    },
...
}
```

Программист из меня, мягко говоря, не очень хороший :(

Comment: А мы знаем ключи словаря?

Comment: @nick_gabpe `Server 0x1ec28c0 (test1)` - тут может меняться всё кроме Server и скобок (); В остальном - всё что слева статично, всё что справа - либо `null`, либо нечто... ключи нужно создавать из того, что слева. Или я не правильно понял Ваш вопрос, извините :(

Comment: Yet another *Useless use of cat*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросал парсер. Замените `for line in text.splitlines():` на `for line in sys.stdin:` и должно работать без строки `text`:

```
import re

text = '''
Server 0x1ec28c0 (test1)
    Server:                              test1.ru
    Status:                              Slave, Running
    Protocol:                            MySQLBackend
    Port:                                3306
    Server Version:                      123-log
    Node Id:                             12
    Master Id:                           13
    Slave Ids:                           
    Repl Depth:                          1
    Slave delay:                         0
    Last Repl Heartbeat:                 Fri Aug 25 15:38:49 2017
    Number of connections:               23
    Current no. of conns:                1
    Current no. of operations:           0
Server 0x1ec1a50 (test2)
    Server:                              test2.gn
    Status:                              Master, Running
    Protocol:                            MySQLBackend
    Port:                                3306
    Server Version:                      023-log
    Node Id:                             13
    Master Id:                           -1
    Slave Ids:                           12, 19 
    Repl Depth:                          0
    Last Repl Heartbeat:                 Fri Aug 25 15:38:59 2017
    Number of connections:               456
    Current no. of conns:                7
    Current no. of operations:           0
'''

server_dict = None
data_info = dict()

for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue

    parts = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        server_name = parts[0]

        # Чтобы вытащить название
        match = re.search('Server .+ \((.+)\)', server_name)
        if match:
            server_name = match.group(1)

        server_dict = dict()
        data_info[server_name] = server_dict
        continue

    # Первой строкой должно быть название сервера, если сервер еще не найден
    if server_dict is None:
        continue

    # К ключу и значению применение функции strip
    key, value = map(str.strip, parts)

    server_dict[key] = value


print(data_info)
print()

import json
print(json.dumps(data_info, ensure_ascii=True, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Консоль:

```
{'test1': {'Server': 'test1.ru', 'Status': 'Slave, Running', 'Protocol': 'MySQLBackend', 'Port': '3306', 'Server Version': '123-log', 'Node Id': '12', 'Master Id': '13', 'Slave Ids': '', 'Repl Depth': '1', 'Slave delay': '0', 'Last Repl Heartbeat': 'Fri Aug 25 15:38:49 2017', 'Number of connections': '23', 'Current no. of conns': '1', 'Current no. of operations': '0'}, 'test2': {'Server': 'test2.gn', 'Status': 'Master, Running', 'Protocol': 'MySQLBackend', 'Port': '3306', 'Server Version': '023-log', 'Node Id': '13', 'Master Id': '-1', 'Slave Ids': '12, 19', 'Repl Depth': '0', 'Last Repl Heartbeat': 'Fri Aug 25 15:38:59 2017', 'Number of connections': '456', 'Current no. of conns': '7', 'Current no. of operations': '0'}}

{
    "test1": {
        "Current no. of conns": "1",
        "Current no. of operations": "0",
        "Last Repl Heartbeat": "Fri Aug 25 15:38:49 2017",
        "Master Id": "13",
        "Node Id": "12",
        "Number of connections": "23",
        "Port": "3306",
        "Protocol": "MySQLBackend",
        "Repl Depth": "1",
        "Server": "test1.ru",
        "Server Version": "123-log",
        "Slave Ids": "",
        "Slave delay": "0",
        "Status": "Slave, Running"
    },
    "test2": {
        "Current no. of conns": "7",
        "Current no. of operations": "0",
        "Last Repl Heartbeat": "Fri Aug 25 15:38:59 2017",
        "Master Id": "-1",
        "Node Id": "13",
        "Number of connections": "456",
        "Port": "3306",
        "Protocol": "MySQLBackend",
        "Repl Depth": "0",
        "Server": "test2.gn",
        "Server Version": "023-log",
        "Slave Ids": "12, 19",
        "Status": "Master, Running"
    }
}
```

---

**PS.** Если важен порядок ключей в словаре, тогда вместо `dict` нужно использовать [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict): `from collections import OrderedDict` (это не актуально уже с версии 3.6, т.к. `dict` начинает поддерживать порядок ключей)

Comment: Ругается на `parts = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)` когда получает аргументом `Server 0x1ec28c0 (test1)` - `split() takes no keyword argument` :(

Comment: @user264802, попробуйте заменить на `parts = line.split(':', 1)`

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, в этом случае всё работает как надо!

Comment: @user264802, ;)

Comment: Как у вас сложно... *У нас есть проблема. Возьмём модуль re. Теперь у нас две проблемы*

Comment: @0andriy, ну, регулярки они такие :) Но я решил, что проще регуляркой вытащить, чем обрезать по количеству символов, т.к. не факт что это закономерно (ведь автор не показал `все` данные), или сделать разбиение строки по символу-разделителю :)

Comment: `line.split()[2].strip('()')` не нравится?

Comment: @0andriy, тоже сойдет :)

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь помог, максимально коротко и компактно постарался написать под ваш формат данных:

```
import sys
import re

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

res = {}
current_key = None

for line in lines:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    if line.startswith(' '):
        name, value = line.split(':', 1)
        res[current_key][name.strip()] = value.strip()
    else:
        key = re.match('.*\((.*)\)', line).group(1)
        res[key] = {}
        current_key = key

print(res)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66062/discussion-on-answer-by----dictionary--stdin).